# What is the difference between `using` and `import` in Julia when building a module?

Tags: julia

**Question:** What is the difference between `using` and `import` in Julia when I'm building my own module?

**My guess based on reading the docs:** `using` is used to bring another module into the name-space of the current module. `import` is used to bring specific types/functions/variables from other modules into the name-space of the current module.

So, how wrong am I?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The Julia [Modules documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v0.6/manual/modules/) states:

> The `import` keyword [...] *only
>   operates on a single name at a time*. It does not add modules to be
>   searched the way `using` does. `import` also differs from `using` in that
>   functions must be imported using `import` *to be extended with new
>   methods*. [...] *Functions whose names are only visible via `using` cannot be extended*.

(Emphasis mine.)

For example, you can use `import` to add methods to `Base.show` to pretty-print your own types, but not with `using`.

There is also `importall` that imports all exported names of a module.

*(This answer refers to Julia 0.6; the documentation was reworded for 1.0.)*

Comment: Very clear thank you (+1+Tick). I actually read that exact passage before asking the question, but clearly didn't decipher the meaning. Your emphasis was very helpful.

Comment: Could I say `using` is restrictive than `import` since it forbids the name to be extended? Or maybe there is something `using` could do but `import` could not.

Comment: What does the documentation mean when it says "Functions whose names are only visible via `using` cannot be extended"? Specifically, what does "visible" mean in the context of function names?

Answer (score 68):

The [documentation](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.4/manual/modules/#Summary-of-module-usage-1) (updated link for Julia 1.4) about this is excellent. Here's the excerpt which I find to be the most succinct summary:

(a demo module to make the examples below specific)

```
module MyModule

export x, y

x() = "x"
y() = "y"
p() = "p"

end
```

(this is a table in the documentation, but StackOverflow still won't add support for tables so... reformatted)

Command

- `using MyModule`

  - in-scope: All exported names (`x` and `y`), `MyModule.x`, `MyModule.y`, and `MyModule.p`
  - extensible: `MyModule.x`, `MyModule.y`, and `MyModule.p`
- `using MyModule: x, p`

  - in-scope: `x` and `p`
  - extensible: (nothing)
- `import MyModule`

  - in-scope: `MyModule.x`, `MyModule.y`, and `MyModule.p`
  - extensible: `MyModule.x`, `MyModule.y`, and `MyModule.p`
- `import MyModule.x, MyModule.p`

  - in-scope: `x` and `p`
  - extensible: `x` and `p`
- `import MyModule: x, p`

  - in-scope: `x` and `p`
  - extensible: `x` and `p`

Comment: My mind is blown... I hadn't realized that nowadays, `using` allows import for extension.

Answer (score 7):

A summary of the main difference, in a way that I find easy to remember:

1. `using NiceStuff` allows *usage* access to exported names without the module qualifier, which `import NiceStuff` doesn't; and
2. `import NiceStuff: nice` allows *extension* access (adding methods) to the specified function without the module qualifier, which `using NiceStuff: nice` doesn't.

And a minor difference:
`X as Y` syntax is allowed for individual identifiers with both `using` and `import` (`using Random: randstring as rstr`, `import Random: randstring as rstr`) but for the module name itself, `import Random as Rnd` is allowed while `using Random as Rnd` is an error.

Some other points I found useful from the [Modules docs page](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/modules/)

> `using ModuleName` is the only form for which export lists matter at all.

> `import NiceStuff` is equivalent to `using NiceStuff: NiceStuff`.