# VSCode doesn't show anything in workspace

Tags: visual-studio-code, julia

Using latest VSCode with Julia. I open a folder, and the Workspace panel is completely empty. I cannot use any refactoring capabilities due to this.

Also, if I click add folder to workspace the workspace panel remains empty.

What can I do?

Comment: show screenshot of each step? or a gif?

Answer (score 0):

The workspace is typically empty until you run some code, then populates with the active variables and any packages you've included. If you run a simple script with just a `using` or `import` command, then you'll see the package in the workspace (e.g., `using ModelingToolkit` will bring all of MTK into the workspace). See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27086159/what-is-the-difference-between-using-and-import-in-julia-when-building-a-mod) for a further discussion of the difference between them depending on what kind of refactoring you want to do.